# Button is not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have the button "saveStats" that is seems to not accept clicking.

On the emulator there is no animation of clicking.

I have tried to do clean and restart Eclipse, didnt work.

I also have CheckBox widget that works fine, only the button dont work. here is my code:

Thank for helping :)

```
Button saveStats;

CheckBox ageCheck, heightCheck, weightCheck, fatCheck;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.set_personal_data);

        saveStats = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveStats);

        ageCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAge);
        heightCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxHeight);
        weightCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxWeight);     
        fatCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxFat);

        saveStats.setOnClickListener(this);
        ageCheck.setOnClickListener(this);
        heightCheck.setOnClickListener(this);
        weightCheck.setOnClickListener(this);
        fatCheck.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.saveStats:
    {
         Toast.makeText(this, "working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          return;
        }
    case R.id.checkBoxAge:
    {
        if(ageCheck.isChecked())
            Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return;
    }
////
////
////
////....
```

Button XML code:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveStats"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="save" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement `OnClickListener()` doing it this way

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
```

then `override` your `onClick()`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    ...
}
```

Just a note. Another way to do this would be to declare the same click function in your xml for each `Button` then write that function in your java code. This prevents you from needing to `implements OnClickListener` and declaring your `Buttons` and setting `onClickListener()` inside your code. Which way you do it depends on what you like best but just another option. Here's a little example:

in xml for each `Button` declare a function

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn1"
    ...
    android:onClick="functionName"/>
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn2"
    ...
    android:onClick="functionName"/>
```

then in your java code:

```
public void functionName(View v)   
{
    ... switch on your id just like you would the other way
}
```

The method just needs to be `public`, accept a `View` as its only `param`, and be the same name as what you declared in your `xml`

Comment: I did override and its not working. And why the button dont work and CheckBox do work?

Comment: You need to change your `return` to `break`. Return is used to exit a method and return some value which is `void` in `onClick()`. `break` is used to exit the `switch`. Even if this did work, if you decided to add behavior in the method no matter which `View` was clicked, the code would never run

Comment: return finishes the methos so the switch will end too.
I dont get the code before the return.

Comment: Please just change it to see we are correct. It will take you 3 seconds

Comment: Its not correct.
I fixed it by changing the position of the button in the linear layout, its some how worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have not use break statement. Make sure your class implements OnClickListener

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.saveStats :
        Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.checkBoxAge :
                         //dosomething
        break;
    }

}
```

For displaying toast use activity context. To know why check the answer by commonsware in the below link

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

Example

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="Button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Button2" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:text="CheckBox" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

CheckBox cb ; 
Button b,b1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    cb.setOnClickListener(this);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
     case R.id.button1 :
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button clicked1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
     case R.id.button2 :
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button clicked2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
     case R.id.checkBox1:
         if(cb.isChecked())
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "check box clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

    }       
}
}
```

Comment: I dont need break, i cast return.

Comment: you don't return because onClick method return type is void

Comment: @tomer use break statement and also use activity context in place of this for displaying toast

Comment: R.id.saveStats is not getting clicked. i cant see the Toast message.

Comment: @tomer it should if you use break statement

Comment: @tomer check the example. you should atleast get it correct now.

Comment: Its not correct.
I fixed it by changing the position of the button in the linear layout, its some how worked.

Comment: @tomer whats not correct?. what i posted is a working code on my samsing galaxy s3 device.